# Angular 2 image src not respecting webpack alias

Tags: angular, webpack

When using aliases as shown below, path is resolved

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
    <img src="~images/feed-slider/icon_1.png" [alt]="feed.alt">
</md-list-item>
```

But if I use an alias as follows, path is not resolved

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
    <img [src]="'~images/feed-slider/' + feed.image" [alt]="feed.alt">
</md-list-item>
```

Someone happened to stump upon this same issue and can share a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `<img src="~images/feed-slider/{{ feed.image }}">`?

Comment: I tried that, but that doesn't work in angular. The dynamic variable there {{ feed.image }} will not be escaped.